# List files that will be overwritten by tar extraction

Tags: shell, tar

Say I have a tarball `~/foo.tar` containing

```
foo/
foo/bar.txt
foo/baz.txt
foo/qux/
foo/qux/corge.txt
foo/qux/grauply.txt
```

And in my home directory `~` I have an existing `foo` directory and the existing files

```
foo
├── bar.txt
├── elvis.txt
├── presley
│   └── graceland.txt
└── qux
    └── corge.txt
```

If I extract this tarball in `~`, the following files will be overwritten:

```
~/foo/bar.txt
~/foo/qux/corge.txt
```

Is there a simple one-liner that will list those files for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $(tar -tzf foo.tar);do ls -d ~/$i 2>/dev/null;done
```